# MySQL compare two lists to say does they exists in each other

Tags: mysql, relation

I am writing app, and I have three tables (`places,` categories`and`main_categories`).

`Main categories` are array of list of categories ids (like main category "Sport" can have "Football stadiums" and "pools"). I am trying to ask the backend for places from main category. I have problem, because places can also have multiple categories, so I have records like this :

Main categories table :

```
| main_category | categories |
| ------------- | ---------- |
|     sport     |   1,3,7,8  |
```

---

places table :

```
|     place_name   | categories |
| ---------------- | ---------- |
| xxx team statium |   1,8,11   |
```

How can I display in MySQL places with in main_category list?

For example above sport should show all places with categories 1,3,7 and 8.

Comment: IS your categories column a text column? Please edit and show you table Explainer.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462) **Well yes!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables in order to find out the corresponding place_name for each `main_categories categories` column, the problem here is that `categories` is a text list.

You really should consider using a n:n relationship with a pivot table and a specific table for category. Something like `maincategories_category` for the `main_categories` table and another for the `places` table like `places_category`.

So you'll end up with 5 tables:

category:

```
| category      |
| 1             |
| 3             |
| 7             |
| 8             |
| 11            |
```

main_categories table :

```
| main_category |
|     sport     |
```

main_categories_category pivot table:

```
| id | main_category | category |
| 1  | sport         | 1        |
| 2  | sport         | 3        |
| 3  | sport         | 7        |
| 1  | sport         | 8        |
```

places table :

```
|     place_name   |
| ---------------- |
| xxx team statium |
```

places_category pivot table:

```
| id | place_name       | category |
| 1  | xxx team statium | 1        |
| 1  | xxx team statium | 8        |
| 1  | xxx team statium | 11       |
```

Then you can play with queries. I.e:

```
select place_name from places_category 
where category IN 
  (
   select category from main_categories_category 
   where main_category = 'sport'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you table `sport` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sport (id int, name varchar(20));
INSERT INTO TABLE sport VALUES
   (1,'Footbal'),
   (3,'Snooker'),
   (7,'Cricket'),
   (8,'AnotherSport'),
   (9,'this one is not mentioned');
```

then you could do:

```
SELECT 
   id, name

FROM sport
INNER JOIN categories ON 
     INSTR( CONCAT(',',categories,','), CONCAT(',',sport.id,','))>0 AND
       main_category='sport';
```

see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=28985d73e4d80bf3ff4676e3edb1e5c0)